# Custom Error show with constraints violation SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, sql-server-2014

I am new to `SQL Server 2014`. I created the table `student`, I made three columns as below. The `melicode` has the `CHECK` constraints and it works well when you want you use `Edit top 200 rows`. When you try to give the `melicode` a number less than two, you face a `Errorbox`; but the problem here: can I print an custom error box to say something, if the constraint is violated, for instance `"The melicode range starts from 2"`.

[image]

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[student](
    [stdid] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [stdname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [melicode] [char](10) NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] 

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[student]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([melicode]>(2)))
```

I tried the below code to implement it, but face with error:

```
IF  melicode < 2
    RAISERROR ('melicode can not be less than 2',0,1)
GO
```

Comment: Where did you try to put the code for RAISERROR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Custom Error Msg error in Sql Server as below:
Note: MsgNum should be greater than 50000

```
exec sp_addmessage @msgnum=50009,@severity=1,@msgtext='melicode can not be less than 2'
```

Message created can be found here:

```
 SELECT * FROM SYS.messages
```

Your Code should goes like below:

```
BEGIN TRY

UPDATE STATEMENT GOES HERE  
OR  
INSERT STATEMENT GOES HERE

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

RAISERROR(50009,1,1)

END CATCH
```